# Does there exist a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2 \to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T((1,-2))=(1,1)$, $T(0,-4)=(0,1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

> Does there exist a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T((1,-2))=(1,1)$, $T(0,-4)=(0,1)$? If it exists, find $T(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

I think it is a linear transformation but i don't know how would I go about proving it since I dont know how would I go about applying the rules $T(u + v)=T(u) + T(v)$ or $T(\lambda u) = \lambda T(u)$.

Comment: Convert $(x,y)$ to $a(1,-2) + b(0,-4)$, where $(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2$. This is a pair of linear equations:

$$\begin{align*}
1a+0b &= x\\
-2a-4b &= y
\end{align*}$$

Comment: **Theorem:** Suppose $v_1,\ldots v_n$ is a basis of $V$ and $w_1,\ldots,w_n\in W$. Then there exists
a unique linear map $T:V\to W$ such that
$$T(v_j)=w_j$$
for each $j=1,\ldots,n$.

Comment: peterwhy
 I have x and y equals as a and b respectively, then what do I do with this?

Comment: Note that the list $(1,-2),(0,-4)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Thus, your goal should be to express $(x,y)$ as a linear combination of $(1,-2)$ and $(0,-4)$.

Comment: Then with the linear combination I can express it as T(x,y), so does that prove that the linear transformation exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does there exist a linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(1,-2)=(1,1)$, $T(0,-4)=(0,1)$?

Yes. Since the list $(1,−2),(0,−4)$ is a basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $(1,1),(0,1)\in\mathbb{R}^2$. Then, there exists a unique linear map $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ such that $T(1,-2)=(1,1)$ and $T(0,-4)=(0,1)$ (See the theorem I have written in my comment).

> If it exists, find $T(x,y)$ for all $(x,y)$ $\in \mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that $(x,y)=x(1,-2)-\frac{1}{4}(2x+y)(0,-4)$. Thus,
$$T(x,y)=xT(1,-2)-\frac{1}{4}(2x+y)T(0,-4)=x(1,1)-\frac{1}{4}(2x+y)(0,1).$$
Therefore,
$$\boxed{T(x,y)=\left(x,\frac{1}{2}x-\frac{1}{4}y\right)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

@Peterwhy answered your question. A linear transformation is determined (defined?) by its values on a basis. You should realize that $v_1=(1,-2)^T$ and $v_2=(0,-4)^T$ is a basis in $R^2$. Now for any $(x,y)^T\in R^2$, solving the system of linear equations written by Peterwhy basically answered your question. It should be $a=x,b=\frac{-2x-y}{4}$. Since $(x,y)^T=xv_1+\frac{-2x-y}{4}v_2$, $T(x,y)=xT(v_1)+\frac{-2x-y}{4}T(v_2)=(x,x)^T+(0,\frac{-2x-y}{4})^T=(x,\frac{2x-y}{4})^T$.